# Manage Skype call with Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, skype, botframework

I'd like to be able to manage voice skype calls using [Microsoft Bot Framework](https://dev.botframework.com) and creating Skype Bot I see this option:

[image]

I read **Limited Preview**, do I have to make a special request or is it enough my account I used to create Skype Bot? In the first case how to do it?

Finally, where I can find documentation to start learning how to develop this process? For example, where I can find a webhook for this service?

What I would like to to is to call to Bot by phone call then analyze speech, analize it by Luis and/or Bot Framework then reply to user by text to Speech.

Is it a reasonable scenario? Is it the way or is there another solution?

Thanks

Comment: Here is a good article on how it works internally https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tsmatsuz/2016/10/22/build-skype-calling-bot-with-microsoft-bot-framework/ and here is a sample bot https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/examples/demo-skype-calling/app.js you can try

Answer (score 1):

The Skype Calling API is now available in the bot framework as of V3 which was released just a couple of weeks ago.  The API lets your bot answer calls, record audio, recognize speech (using LUIS congnitive service) or accept digits from the user on the dial pad.  You can combine these actions and create complex dialogs with the user.

You can see all the info about the Calling API at https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/skype/calling/

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Voice is bot yet available in the botframework.

Not sure that it will be available soon.

Comment: Hi Etienne,
Thanks for your support.
I hope the internal team take care of localization.
I understand is a preview and I will wait but I hope internal team will take special focus on that.
I well know english is the most important language but for real life business cases, often we need to work with our local lanuage.
What I would suggest is to don't put attention into localization as secondary option,  but to consider it as one of key features to release soon else we will not be albe to convice our customers to put interest into this amazing techology.